# When applying for a mortgage, can it also cover outstanding debts?

Tags: mortgage, borrowing, debt

When applying for a mortgage, can you also add some extra on (£10k) to cover car finance? Or is there any benefit of keeping them separate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That really depends on the lender, and in the current climate this is extremely unlikely.

In the past it was possible to get a loan which is higher than the value of the house (deposit considered), usually on the basis that the buyer is going to improve the property (extend, renovate, etc.) and this increase the value of the property.

Responsible lenders required some evidence of the plans to do this, but less responsible ones simply seem to have given the money.

Here in the UK this was often based on the assumption that property value tends to rise relatively quickly anyway so a seemingly-reasonable addition to the loan on top of the current value of the property will quickly be covered.

That meant that indeed some people have been able to get a loan which is higher than the cost of the purchase, even without concrete plans to actively increase the value of the property.

Today the situation is quite different, lenders are a lot more careful and I can't see this happening.

All that aside - had it been possible, is it a good idea? I find it difficult to come up with a blanket rule, it really depends on many factors - 
On the one hand  mortgage interest rates tend to be significantly lower than shorter term interest rates and from that point of view, it makes sense, right?!
However - they are usually very long term, often with limited ability to overpay, which means the interest will be paid over a longer period of time.

Comment: +1 for comparing short-term high-percentage borrowing with long-term low-percentage borrowing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but should you be even trying to get a mortgage if you can't aford at least a 5% deposit?

Prove you do want the house by doing without a new car for a few years...